# Чи дійсно слово "товариство" пішло від ленінсько-більшовицького "товаріщі"?

Tags: вживання-слів, етимологія, from-russian

Чи дійсно слово "товариство" пішло від ленінсько-більшовицького "товаріщі"?
Поважні люди кажуть, що українські націоналісти не вживали звернення "товариство". 
Насправді, кажуть, зверталися як

> Друзі, Брати, **Побратими**, Сестри, Посестри

Подекуди в українських творах трапляється "товариство",
але лише після приходу більшовицької окупації.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ні, звісно, ні.

«[Товариш](http://sum.in.ua/s/tovarysh)»:

- […], Еней Евандрові сказав: / «Хоть ти і грек, та цар правдивий, / Тобі латинці вороги; / Я твій товариш буду щирий, / Латинці і мені враги. […]» *<sub>//І. Котляревський, «Енеїда», частина V (1821)</sub>*.
- Ой застогнав сивий пугач / В степу на могилі, / Зажурились чумаченьки, / Тяжко зажурились. / «Благослови, отамане, / Коло села стати, / Та понесем товариша / В село причащати.» *<sub>//Т. Шевченко, «У неділю не гуляла…» (1844)</sub>*.
- [Жірондист:] Чи він мене прийняв би товаришем з собою у дорогу? [Жінка:] Я думаю. А то й спитати можна. *<sub>//Леся Українка, «Три хвилини» (1905)</sub>*.

«[Товариство](http://sum.in.ua/s/tovarystvo)»:

- У неділю вранці-рано / Синє море грало, / Товариство кошового / На раді прохало: […]. *<sub>Т. Шевченко, «Сліпий» (1845)</sub>*.
- У товаристві лад — усяк тому радіє; / Дурне безладдя лихо діє, / І діло, як на гріх, / Не діло — тільки сміх. *<sub>Л. Глібов, «Лебідь, Щука й Рак» (1853)</sub>*.
- Поважна та розумна, вона не любила забавок, не любила веселого шумливого товариства, хоч була ще й молода. *<sub>//І. Нечуй-Левицький, «Князь Єремія Вишневецький» (1897)</sub>*.
- [Дженні:] Авжеж, ви все були в блискучім товаристві, часами й при дворі у короля. *<sub>//Леся Українка, «У пущі», (1909)</sub>*.

23 грудня 1873 року у Львові було утворене [Літературне товариство імені Т. Шевченка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) (у 1892 році назву змінено на Наукове товариство ім. Т. Шевченка).

Тобто ми бачимо вживання цього слова з часів «задовго до СРСР» і майже до самого його створення. Я не знаю про популярність слів «товариш» та «товариство» у різні роки, можливо, що колись воно мало тенденцію до виходу з ужитку, а повернулося частково через вплив російського «товарищ» — але то дуже малоімовірно. Радше за все, воно завжди існувало в українській мові (з часів Русі), просто в радянські роки його вживання набуло певного відтінку, що воно його не мало раніше.

Comment: Щодо Лесі Українки - у 1905 році вже були "революційна ситуація" і в ті роки вже формувався чи був сформований лексикон, яким вже потім користувалися більшовики. У цьому творі жирондіст - французький революціонер і там є, наприклад, і такі рядки: "Жірондист

(увіходить у свою камеру і, спиняючись на порозі, звертається до товаришів, що на коридорі)

До завтрього, товариші! Запевне, / побачимось… 
[Жірондистка] (з коридора)

На ешафоті, може!

Comment: @Artemix, так, Ви праві. Я, якщо честно багато не шукав (зовсім не шукав!) — в даному випадку просто поставив дати до прикладів з СУМ-11. Вони показують широкий діапазон дат: 1821–1909 — і мені цього вистачило. Може, є й кращі приклади.

Comment: Я згоден з вашою відповіддю, в мене зауваження тільки щодо «Трьох хвилин».

Answer (score 21):

Ні, це слово з'явилося набагато раніше, ніж комунізм, і, сподіваюся, ще довго існуватиме після остаточного зникнення комунізму.

У словнику Макса Фасмера¹ [міститься](https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D1%82/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%89) етимологія слова <sub>рос.</sub>*товарищ*, як
**запозиченого із тюркського слова *tavar*** у значенні *«майно, худоба»*
плюс суфікс `-иш` у значенні *«супутник»*.

- *Товар* (у значенні *«худоба»*) широко використовується в українській мові. Наприклад, оцей звуковий файл ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrnVrb0L8MU); *обережно, ненормативна лексика*) містить таку фразу:

  > *Коли — йде пастух і **товар** кличе в череду. Повідмикав дядько овечок, коровку, бика, коня, все відпустив.*
- Суфікс `-иш` також зустрічається у словах виду *Черниш*.

---

**Історична довідка**.
*Товаришами* називали один одного купці на Русі, які торгували одним і тим само *товаром*. Іншими словами, *«колега, спільник по торгівлі тим само товаром»*.
З часом, слово *товариш* пройшло через процес генералізації² і набуло більш широкого значення *«колега, спільник»*, без прив'язки до торгівлі.

---

**Стосовно використання цього слова комуністами**. Ми не можемо точно дізнатися, *чому* комуністи запозичили саме це слово, але можемо зазначити, що перші комуністи були цілком німецькомовними, а **німецьке слово Genosse має таке само походження**. Ось, що пише словник³:

- Слово */Ґеноссе/* походить від `ge-` + `*nauta–`, що разом означає *«людина, яка має ту само худобу»*

Також див. англійське слово [*neat*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=neat) у значенні «бик, корова».

[Ця відповідь](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/31895/1980) стверджує, що префікс `Ge-` виражає об'єднаність або спільну ідентичність, напр.  *Geschwister* (брати-сестри, дослівно «сестринство»), *Genosse* (товариш) тощо.

Тому цілком ймовірно, що російська комуністична партія, яка мала відповідне німецьке коріння, могла почати використовувати слово <sub>рос.</sub>**товарищ** в якості кальки з <sub>нім.</sub>**„Genosse“**.

---

¹ Стаття Фасмера оригінальною мовою (рос.):

> Обычно объясняется из тюрк., ср. тур., чагат. *tаvаr* «имущество, скот, товар» (см. това́р) +еš, iš «товарищ»; см. Корш, AfslPh 9, 674 и сл.; Мi. ТЕl., Nachtr. 1, 57; ЕW 359.
>   Др. тюрк. этимологию предлагает Рясянен (ZfslPh 20, 448: от чув. *tavra* «по кругу» + iš «спутник»).
>   О суф. -iš, -уš см. Брандт, РФВ 25, 31.

² [Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change#Types) — це процес таксономічного зсуву вгору. Наприклад, слово «ксерокс» — це назва однієї компанії, але згодом воно почало означати копіювальні машини будь-якого виробника.

³ [Стаття](http://www.wissen.de/wortherkunft/genosse) з етимологічного словника німецької мови:

> **Genosse**: die Bezeichnung stammt aus dem Westgermanischen und gehört zu der Wortgruppe von → *genießen*; es geht auf germ. `*nauta–` „Vieh, Besitz“ zurück, das sich auch in engl. `neat` und schwed. `nöt` „Rinder, Vieh“ bezeugen lässt; die Ausgangsbedeutung von *Genosse* ist also **„jemand, der das gleiche Vieh hat“**; daraus entwickelte sich später die allgemeine Bedeutung „Gefährte, Begleiter“ […]

Comment: Власне, слова «товариш» і «товариство» є навіть у «найкласичнішій» українській літературі (Т. Шевченко, Леся Українка). Тому запитання видається якимось дивним. Може, автор мав саме як звернення до колективу «Товариші, …» — а не просто слово?

Answer (score 3):

Мені здалося, що у байці Григорія Сковорди ["Собака і вовк"](http://scovoroda.info/stories.php?page=23&theme=light), що увійшла до збірки ["Байки Харківські"](https://books.google.com/books?id=NlwzBgAAQBAJ) та була написані в часі 1766-1774 років ми знаходимо:

> — Прошу мене любити та жалувати, панове мої,— казав Вовк з удаваною чемністю.— Ви мене надзвичайно вщасливите, коли дозволите мені бути третім вашим товаришем. Вважатиму це собі за велику честь.

але потім я зрозумів, що дійсно, він писав на доволі специфічному діалекті (що нам видаватиметься сумішшю російської і української мов) і не може бути аргументом. Та відповідь залишена для зручності користувачів.

Comment: @DmytroNezhynskyi, на жаль, Г. Сковорода в даному випадку не аргумент. Чому? Тому що він писав на доволі специфічному діалекті (що нам видаватиметься сумішшю російської і української мов). У сучасних виданнях його, як правило, **перекладають** на сучасну українську. У байці «Собака і вовк» у нього немає слова «товарищ».

Comment: **[Оригінал](http://litopys.org.ua/skovoroda/skov105.htm)**: *— Прошу меня жаловать и любить, государи мои, — говорил с придворною ужимкою Волк. — Вы меня высоколЂпно ощасливить в состояніи, если соизволите удостоить меня мЂста быть третим вашим **другом**, чего лестно ожидаю.*

Answer (score -2):

Товариші — це ті, хто грабували спільно товар. Іншими словами — це спiлка грабіжників.

Comment: Цікаво. А підтвердження цієї теорії хоч якісь є? Бо так більше схоже на жарт, якщо чесно.

Comment: Єдина сторінка з таким самим означенням і без аргументації http://zkan.com.ua/sho/jaka-negativna-istorija-u-slova-tovarish.html